# Why is [xx chars] resulted instead of the whole phrase?

Tags: python, parsing, split, char, python-unittest

I am re-doing the https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/7 by splitting the input into useful information. When I run the following scripts:

script.py

```
def parse_line(input):
    d = dict(x.split(" bags contain ") for x in input.split("\n"))
    return(d)
```

test_script.py

```
import unittest
import script

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_parse(self):
        data = """vibrant plum bags contain 5 faded blue bags, 6 dotted black bags.
faded blue bags contain no other bags.
dotted black bags contain no other bags."""
        self.assertEqual(0, script.parse(data))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The output in the terminal shows:
*AssertionError: 0 != {'vibrant plum': '5 faded blue bags, 6 do[79 chars]gs.'}*

Why is this *[79 chars]* resulted instead of the whole phrase? I tried to look up in internet without success. What does this mean and what can be done?

Comment: The error string is just truncating the right side to be more readable. Internally it's the whole thing that didn't match

Comment: That's just how `unittest` handles printing long objects. Instead of unreadable wall of text you get enough to identify the issue. Why would you need whole phrase when it's clearly not equal to 0?

Comment: I understand that it will be the error string because of the 0 that I put. The whole phrase I mean "5 faded blue bags, 6 dotted black bags." instead of "5 faded blue bags, 6 do[79 chars]gs."

Comment: OK, when I put the right stuff on the LHS the test works. Thanks for your clarification!